# Perl fork() subroutines 'free to wrong pool' error

Tags: multithreading, perl, fork

I asked an earlier question regarding multithreading where I would attempt to run two (similar) subroutines in parallel.  The consensus was that although the code looked ok (using threads) I should try using fork() as an alternative to see if the problem went away.  The problem I am seeing is a 'free to wrong pool' error with the perl interpreter crashing.

The script is trying to run manual PLMN searches on two different handsets at the same time and report when it is finished for both handsets.  I am simultaneously scanning two different adb logcat logs to search for the scan completed string in each log, but I am getting a 'free to wrong pool' error once the string is found in the subroutine dutmplmn.  Is this now a case of a waiting for the other subroutine to complete correctly, or are my subroutines too similar for the perl interpreter to cope?  I think the first subroutine completes and exits without waiting for the second subroutine to fully complete.  The code fails at this point >> unlink($file); exit;

I am using the latest strawberry perl 5.18.1.1 on Windows7

Here's the fork() code...

```
use strict;
use Win32::OLE;
use EFS_Handle;
use HelperFunctions;
use threads;
use warnings;

#### Various ADB command sequences follow ####
#### Start of multithread to run the same function on different android handsets ####

  my $file = new File::Temp( UNLINK => 0 );

  my $new_pid = fork();
  die "fork failed $!" unless defined $new_pid;   # this is uncommon

  # Task 1 - in the background
  if ($new_pid == 0) {
      dutmplmn();   
      unlink($file);
      exit;            
  }

  use POSIX ':sys_wait_h';
  while (! waitpid $new_pid, &WNOHANG) {   # WNOHANG => non-blocking wait
      refmplmn(); 
   }

  sub dutmplmn{

     open my $fh_DUT, '>', "output_DUT.txt" or die "Cannot open output_DUT.txt: $!";
     my $pid_DUT = open my $log_DUT, "-|", "adb -s 42d8d7dd logcat -b radio";

     sleep(2);

     print "\n\t" . DUTcurTime() . " :\t DUT Time at start of MPLMN search";
     system('adb -s 42d8d7dd shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER');

     while(<$log_DUT>) {
      $fh_DUT->print($_);
      last if m/showPlmn='true'/;
     }
  kill "TERM", $pid_DUT;
  close $log_DUT;
  print "\n\t" . DUTcurTime() . " :\t DUT Time at End of MPLMN search\n";


  }

  sub refmplmn{       

     open my $fh_REF, '>', "output_REF.txt" or die "Cannot open output_REF.txt: $!";
     my $pid_REF = open my $log_REF, "-|", "adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF logcat";

     sleep(2);

     print "\n\t" . REFcurTime() . " :\t REF Time at start of MPLMN search";
     system('adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER');

     while(<$log_REF>) {
      $fh_REF->print($_);
      last if m/EVENT_NETWORK_SCAN_COMPLETED/;
     }
    kill "TERM", $pid_REF;
    close $log_REF;
    print "\n\t" . REFcurTime() . " :\t REF Time at End of MPLMN search\n";
  }
```

Thanks,
MikG

Comment: I had a simular problem and switched to using the Threads library for it I'm sure that the main subrotine may exit without waiting for the threads to complete but this can be escaped easy.

Comment: When it was suggested to use forks, it may have been suggesting to literally `use forks`. This is a drop-in replacement for `use threads` that works better in some cases.

Comment: On Windows [`fork()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html "perldoc -f fork") is implemented using threads, so I would doubt that using `fork()` would fix anything. Also @AKHolland the documentation for [`use forks`](https://metacpan.org/pod/forks "perldoc forks") mentions that it doesn't allow you to install it on Windows.

Comment: I second Brad's comment. Using fork on Windows will not work as expected on *INUX systems.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies.  So it looks like my options are limited.